# How to polyfill with native code in IE11?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, vue-cli-3

As we all know that IE does not support Array.prototype.includes method, so it should log 'undefined' with Array.protopetype.includes.

However, open I open an app in IE which was built with vue-cli, and I tried to log ' Array.prototype.includes' in console, it unexpectedly log the 'native code', which means that the includes methods now was nativly supported!

Out of my perception，it should log something like 
`function(){....}`

but how could it log 'native code'?I've googled that, but found nothing relative.Online link was showned here: https://gaoshijun1993.github.io/，you can test it with IE

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used:

```js
 if (!Array.prototype.includes) //Dirty-fix za starije preglednike koji ne podrzavaju JavaScript naredbu Array.includes (kao sto je Internet Explorer 6).
                Array.prototype.includes = function (x)
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
                        if (this[i] == x)
                            return true;
                    return false;
                }
```

Here is the full program:

https://github.com/FlatAssembler/ArithmeticExpressionCompiler/blob/master/compiler.html

Comment: He is not asking what you used, he is asking why the polyfill used by Vue-Cli returns `[native code]` instead of `function() {...}`. Also, the code you used is not a good polyfill. Polyfills are supposed to mimic the real function. [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) accepts 2 parameters _(1 required, 1 optional)_. Yours only accepts one, so it will have different behaviors. It may be fine if you're the only one to use it, but that piece of code would never be used in a polyfill library

Comment: thank you for your interpretation，I appended the online link